# reversing sequences without standard libraries in Clojure

Tags: clojure, reverse

I'm trying to go through the problem set at 4clojure.org. I'm on number 23 (reverse a string without using 'reverse' function). I'm getting this error:

> Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long

here's my code:

```
(fn rev [coll] 
  (if (= () coll)
    nil
    ((cons(rev (rest coll))(first coll)))))
```

edited now to this:

```
(fn rev [coll] 
  (if (empty? coll)
    coll
    (concat(rev (rest coll))((list first coll)))))
```

presumably this is from trying to cons the head of the sequence to the end of the rest of the sequence.

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is because you are trying to `cons` a `seq` to an element rather than an element to a `seq`. In other words, your arguments to `cons` are in the wrong order. But, if you corrected the order, you'd just be piecing a list back together in the same order.

Using the same general idea you have, you could turn the second argument into a list by wrapping it in `(list ...)` and then `concat` the two lists together:

```
(fn rev [coll] 
  (if (empty? coll)
    coll
    (concat
      (rev (rest coll))
      (list (first coll)))))
```

You'll discover more concise solutions as you go along.

Comment: i'm not able to get this to run: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Comment: @Ramy In your original code, you have an extraneous set of parenthesis around the last line: `((cons...))` -> `(cons...)`. Make sure you strip those if you are converting your code as above. Copying mine verbatim, I see no problem for the 4Clojure test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Second argument of `cons` in clojure should be a sequence, however, `(first coll)` is not a sequence but an element of a collection. Perhaps you pass the collection of numbers, so `(first coll)` spit a number (long) and clojure cannot create `ISeq` from the number.

```
user=> (doc cons)
-------------------------
clojure.core/cons
([x seq])
  Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
    the rest.
```

You can implement reverse simply like the following:

```
(fn rev [coll]
    (reduce conj () coll))
```

I check the above code and it passed all three test cases in 4clojure site.

Comment: this is great but a bit too dense for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

Like the OP, I've become frustrated trying to construct recursive solutions with `when-let` and `if`, `next` and `last`, etc, etc. So now I'm trying to understand @ntalbs answer and see if I can take this further, studying the Clojure documentation at http://clojuredocs.org/quickref/Clojure%20Core.

**Part #1 -- Observations:**
`cons` is a function of lists, whereas `conj` is a generic function of collections, and `concat` is listed under 'Use(modification)' of sequences, but it returns a Lazy Sequence. So how do these things differ in practice?

1. Argument order matters: you can't `conj` a value and a sequence, only a sequence and a value. For `cons` it's the other way around. `concat` appears to be more forgiving.

   ```
   user=> (type (conj 1 '(2 3 4 5)))
   ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection  clojure.core/conj (core.clj:83)
   user=> (type (cons '(2 3 4 5) 1))
   IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
   ```
2. Three different return types: Cons, PersistentList or LazySeq

   ```
   user=> (type (cons 1 '(2 3 4 5)))
   clojure.lang.Cons
   user=> (type (conj '(2 3 4 5) 1))
   clojure.lang.PersistentList
   user=> (type (concat 1 '(2 3 4 5)))
   clojure.lang.LazySeq
   ```
3. Different behaviour for different types of collections:

   ```
   user=> (cons 3 (sorted-set 5 7 2 7))
   (3 2 5 7)     ; type = Cons, 3 is just appended to the list, 
   user=> (conj (sorted-set 5 7 2 7) 3)
   #{2 3 5 7}    ; type = PersistentTreeSet, with 3 in the correct position.
   user=> (concat 3 (sorted-set 5 7 2 7))   ; LazySeq can't be directly returned, so...(order doesn't matter)
   IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
   ```

To my mind, `conj` has the most straightforward behaviour, so I will use this by preference, unless I actually want a lazy sequence or specifically a list.

**Part #2 -- @Ramy's 'too dense for me'**  Understanding @ntalbs's solution.

The description above suggests that `conj` is the most appropriate method for adding things into a collection, which is exactly what @ntalbs's solution does. The usage for `reduce` is at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce  It's an effective way of applying a function while collecting together the values in a collection.

```
(reduce f val coll)
```

So, `reduce` will apply `f` for each member of the collection, starting with `val`. The call `(reduce conj () coll)` thus takes the collection and first applies `(conj () (first coll))`. Then it applies `(conj result (second coll))`, and `(conj result (third coll))`, etcetera, where `result` is the result of the previous step.

`reduce` looks like a very powerful command.

**Part #3 -- yet another solution**

```
(fn rev [coll]
    (into () coll))
```

From the documentation, `into` appears to be syntactic sugar for `(reduce conj to-coll from-coll)`. I'm not sure if this is elegant or just dense. It does work, though, with minimal key-strokes.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation and solution #1. It's handy. Actually `into` is a function and you can see the source code by `(source into)` in clojure repl.